# Replace infinite thread loop (message pump) with Tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, producer-consumer

In my application I have to listen on multiple different queues and deserialize/dispatch incoming messages received on queues.

Actually, what I am doing to achieve this is that each QueueConnector object creates a new thread on construction, which executes a infinite loop with a blocking call to queue.Receive() to receive next message in queue as exposed by the code below :

```
// Instantiate message pump thread
msmqPumpThread = new Thread(() => while (true)
{
   // Blocking call (infinite timeout)
   // Wait for a new message to come in queue and get it
   var message = queue.Receive();

   // Deserialize/Dispatch message
   DeserializeAndDispatchMessage(message);
}).Start();
```

I'd like to know if this "message pump" can be replaced using Task(s) instead of going through an infinite loop on a new Thread.

I made a task already for the Message receiving part (see below) but I don't really see how to use it for a message pump (Can I recall the same task on completion over and over again, with continuations, replacing infinite loop in separate thread as in the code above ?)

```
Task<Message> GetMessageFromQueueAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Message>();

    ReceiveCompletedEventHandler receiveCompletedHandler = null;

    receiveCompletedHandler = (s, e) =>
    {
       queue.ReceiveCompleted -= receiveCompletedHandler;
       tcs.SetResult(e.Message);
    };

    queue.BeginReceive();

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Will I gain anything by using Tasks instead of an infinite loop in a separate thread (with a blocking call => blocking thread) in this context ? And if yes, how to do it properly ?

Please note that this application don't have a lot of QueueConnector objects, and won't have (maybe 10 connectors MAX), meaning ten Threads max through the first solution, so memory footprint / performance starting threads is not an issue here. I was rather thinking about scheduling performance / CPU usage. Will there be any difference ?

Comment: This is a tipycal producer-consumer scenario that in can be solved using [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) and in particular with [`BlockingCollection<T>.GetConsumingEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Paolo ! 
However to my knowledge, Producer/Consummer queues are more adapted to compute bound tasks (performing intensive computation), whereas TaskCompletionSource/asynchronous functions are more adapted to I/O bound tasks (waiting for something to happen). 
As my problem deals with an I/O bound task (waiting for a Message to come in the queue), I thought TaskCompletionSource would be more approriate. I could be wrong however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will generally have more overhead and less throughput with async code when the count of threads is low. Nonblocking code is most useful when the number of threads is very high causing a) lots of wasted memory due to stacks and b) context switches. It has noticable overhead though because of more allocation, more indirection and more user-kernel-transitions.

For low thread counts (< 100) you probably shouldn't worry. Try to focus on writing maintainable, bug-resistant and simple code. Use threads.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still if each QueueConnector object uses a dedicated thread with an infinite loop to receive messages (my current approach), the threads are going to do a context switch each time they reach the blocking queue.Receive() call. And another context switch back in the thread once a message arrives. Is that correct ?
I have read that Tasks can use the thread pool to lessen startup latency (not needed in my context) but also with a TaskCompletionSource they can use a callback approach, avoiding the use of a thread wile waiting on I/O bound operation (means no context switch?)

Comment: Async nonblocking code causes less context switches. If you want to fund out which version is faster you need to try it out because there are arguments to be made for both. My point was, that it is probably not worth the hassle. How many queue ops do you have per second? Less than 10k? Then it doesn't matter from a perf standpoint.